# code_builder's generated code miss import statements

Tags: flutter

I am using this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/code_builder) to generate code and I think am missing something on how generated code should have import statements. I am using `Reference` to pass `symbol` and `url` hoping that import will be on output but I get none.

Here is the sample of my code

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:code_builder/code_builder.dart';
import 'package:dart_style/dart_style.dart';

/// A .
class Generator {
  /// R
  read() {
    String contents = File('./README.md').readAsStringSync();

    final animal = Class(
      (b) => b
        ..name = 'Animal'
        ..extend = const Reference('MdPage', 'package:md2dart/md2dart.dart') //HERE
        ..constructors.add(
          Constructor(
            (b) => b
              ..initializers.add(refer('super').call([]).code) //TROUBLE HERE TOO
              ..constant = true
              ..optionalParameters.add(
                Parameter(
                  (b) => b
                    ..name = 'key'
                    ..type = refer('Key?', 'package:flutter/material.dart') //HERE
                    ..named = true,
                ),
              ),
          ),
        )
        ..methods.addAll(
          [
            Method(
              (b) => b
                ..name = 'getContent'
                ..body = Code(
                  'return """\n$contents\n""";',
                )
                ..returns = refer('String')
                ..annotations.addAll([refer('override')]),
            ),
          ],
        ),
    );

    final emitter = DartEmitter(
      orderDirectives: true,
    );

    final kode = DartFormatter().format('${animal.accept(emitter)}');

    File('./lib/output.dart').writeAsStringSync(kode);
  }
}
```

output

```dart
class Animal extends MdPage {
  const Animal({Key? key}) : super();

  @override
  String getContent() {
    return """
This is README. 
""";
  }
}
```

But what I want is output to have these 2 imports at the beginning

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:md2dart/md_page.dart';
```

as well as `super();` to be `super(key : key);` as in flutter widgets which I also can't figure out how..

Any help will be much appreciated.